# Is there standard "foreach" function in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

```
Clojure> (doc foreach)
Unable to resolve var: foreach in this context

Clojure> (doc map)
-------------------------
clojure.core/map
([f coll] [f c1 c2] [f c1 c2 c3] [f c1 c2 c3 & colls])
```

Of course, i can use the "map" to mimic "foreach" but the map always return nil, which makes the output ugly in the following function:

```
(defn div618 [p1 p2]
    (let [ratio [0.,0.191,0.236,0.382,0.5,0.618,0.809,1.]
          price (fn [r] (if (<= p1 p2) (+ p1 (* (- p2 p1) r)) (- p1 (* (- p1 p2) r))))]

    (if (<= p1 p2)
        (**map** #(println (format "-------%.3f   %.2f-------" %1 (price %1))) (reverse ratio))
        (**map** #(println (format "-------%.3f   %.2f-------" %1 (price %1)))  ratio))))
```

Sincerely!

Comment: What is `**map**`?  Did you mean to set that name in bold?  Also, you know that you can use newlines anywhere between tokens, right?

Answer (score 72):

I think `doseq` might be what you're looking for:

```
(doseq [i [0 1 2 3]] (println i))
```

However this will still return `nil` - all forms in Clojure will evaluate to some value; there's no equivalent to Common Lisp's `(values)`.

Comment: @z_axis: Tick the check mark on the left to accept an answer.  Also, you might want to upvote it.

Answer (score 12):

As of Clojure 1.7 you can use [`run!`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/run!):

```
user=> (run! println (range 10))

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
=> nil  ; returns nil
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38038089) to [How to print each item of list on separate line clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035839/how-to-print-each-item-of-list-in-separate-line-clojure)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Works like Julia's `foreach`

Answer (score 3):

map is used to apply a function f to every element of the seq, in your case your applying print which returns nil, so you get a intermediate seq of nils which you then throw away. When you want side effects like printing you use doseq.

Clojure does not have a single foreach form map, reduce filter etc. technically these are all foreach forms they all do something to each element in the seq. Also map is lazy your example will only print in the repl cause repl forces lazy seq to realize them selfs say if you pack this in a jar it won't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

You could use doseq or doall. Following is the example using doall.

```
(defn div618 [p1 p2]
    (let [ratio [0.,0.191,0.236,0.382,0.5,0.618,0.809,1.]
          price (fn [r] (if (<= p1 p2) (+ p1 (* (- p2 p1) r)) (- p1 (* (- p1 p2) r))))]

    (doall (map #(println (format "-------%.3f   %.2f-------" %1 (price %1))) (if (<= p1 p2) (reverse ratio) ratio)))))
```

You could also separate the printing from the function calculation like this,

```
(defn div618 [p1 p2]
    (let [ratio [0.,0.191,0.236,0.382,0.5,0.618,0.809,1.]
          price (fn [r] (if (<= p1 p2) (+ p1 (* (- p2 p1) r)) (- p1 (* (- p1 p2) r))))]

    (map (fn [x] [x (price x)]) (if (<= p1 p2) (reverse ratio) ratio))))

(doall (map #(println (format "-------%.3f   %.2f-------" (first %1) (last %1))) (div618 1 2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want clojure's list comprehension, see: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Concepts#List_Comprehension

Comment: Clojure> (for [x (range 10)] (inc x))
(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
Clojure> (for [x (range 10)] (println x))
(nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil)

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn div618 [p1 p2]
  (let [ratio [0.000 0.191 0.236 0.382 0.500 0.618 0.809 1.000]            
        price #(if (<= p1 p2)
                 (-> p2 (- p1) (* %) (+ p1))
                 (-> p1 (- p2) (* %) (- p1)))
        print-all #(doseq [item %]
                     (printf "-------%.3f   %.2f-------\n" item (price item)))]
    (if (<= p1 p2)
      (print-all (reverse ratio))
      (print-all ratio))))
```

Comment: Note: no commas, ad-hoc left-to-right math syntax using thread-first (`->`), and `doseq` which is essentially Clojure's `foreach`.