# How to print each item of list in separate line clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm very new in clojure. I want to print each item of list in newline. I'm trying like this:

```
user=> (def my-list '(1 2 3 4 5 ))
;; #'user/my-list
user=> my-list
;; (1 2 3 4 5)
user=> (apply println my-list)
;; 1 2 3 4 5
;; nil
```

But I want my output must be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
nil
```

can anyone tell me, How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This kind of use case (perform a side effect once for each member of a sequence) is the purpose of [`doseq`](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.core/doseq). Using it here would be like

```
(doseq [item my-list]
   (println item))
```

Note that this will not *print* `nil` but will *return it*. Working with it in the REPL will see the return values of all expressions printed, but doesn't happen in e.g. starting your project as a terminal program.

Answer (score 23):

If you already have a function that you would like to apply to every item in a single sequence, you can use [`run!`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/run!) instead of [`doseq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq) for greater concision:

```
(run! println [1 2 3 4 5])
;; 1
;; 2
;; 3
;; 4
;; 5
;;=> nil
```

`doseq` is useful when the action you want to perform is more complicated than just applying a single function to items in a single sequence, but here `run!` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Another strategy would be to build a string from the list that you want to print and then just print the string.

```
user> (defn unlines [coll]
        (clojure.string/join \newline coll))
#'user/unlines

user> (unlines [1 2 3 4 5])
"1\n2\n3\n4\n5"

user> (println (unlines [1 2 3 4 5]))
1
2
3
4
5
nil
```

Comment: The main difference is when the sequence you're printing is lazy; compare `(run! println (range))` and `(println (unlines (range)))`.

Comment: @SamEstep you're right, it's not quite as useful on an infinite list. Lazy sequences will have to be realized before building the String. But in general, confining side-effecting code to the boundaries is not a bad strategy. A function that returns a String is much more testable than one that prints to the console.

Comment: Agreed. It's just a question of what task specifically needs to be done. In this particular case of printing five already known items separated by newlines, I would say that your `unlines` solution is better. But in the more general case of performing actions (which may involve input or output or both) repeatedly, precalculating the result isn't always an option.